# Why is my link clickable outside the linked text

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZPaw.png

Here is what it looks like right now. Clicking anywhere inside the black border links to the URL. I only want the text "RANKINGS" to be linked.

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
      <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank" rel='noopener noreferrer'><h4 id="title">RANKINGS</h4></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#title {
    margin-top: -10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #e846ff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are adding a Heading element (h4) inside an anchor (a) element.

Even though Anchors are inline elements, meaning they don't take the full width of the screen, you added a Heading element inside that Anchor.

Heading elements are block elements and they do take up the full with of the screen.

It would be better to reverse the html as seen in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Donaldini/pen/VwpgENJ):

```
<h4 id="title">
    <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank" rel='noopener noreferrer'>RANKINGS</a>
</h4>
```

This way you get you wanted.

Comment: `a` elements are transparent, not inline.

Comment: @quentin In my mind anchor elements were always inline and even though this is true for Safari, Chrome, Firefox, IE11 and Edge it would seem this is not in any spec I could find. Mind blown!

So it would seem that it depends on what every browser decides. Though I would assume most follow the idealogy of saying that an anchor is a text-flowing element and not a container.

Answer (score 0):

As h4 is a block level element it takes the entire width of the window. use span tag instead of h4. Also h4 is not valid inside a tag. Still if you want to keep it you need to apply

```
#title{
display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, probably, it's element with value `block` in property `display`. Inspect element and check it in such cases. Block elements have 100% width. If you need, change `display: block;` to `display: inline;` (in headings width 100% set as default) or another value for auto width. Also, you should check `display` of link, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this issue is to give your a element the  width: fit-content; property. This will make the link hug the text and not extend beyond it:

```
<h4 id="title">
    <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank" rel='noopener noreferrer'>RANKINGS</a>
</h4>
```

(CSS:)

```
h4 a{
width: fit-content;
}
```